# How to map an IceFaces <ice:selectInputDate> component on a java.util.Calendar field?

Tags: java, jsf, seam, icefaces

Does anybody knows how can component `<ice:selectInputDate>` be mapped on a `java.util.Calendar` field, not `java.util.Date`?

I am using from [IceFaces](http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component) version 1.8.2, the component `<ice:selectInputDate>`. This component requires to be bound with a `java.util.Date` proeprty. For example, `value="#{bean.myDate}"`, the `myDate` field must be of type `java.util.Date`. But I need my date field to be of type `java.util.Calendar`.

I have tried to use standard converter or a custom one:

1. Standard one: `<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />`  it formats correct the value in GUI, but when setting it on the property `bean.myDate` of type `Calendar` I get following error message:

> [5/3/10 12:09:18:398 EEST] 00000021
> lifecycle I WARNING: FacesMessage(s)
> have been enqueued, but may not have
> been displayed.
> sourceId=j_id12:j_id189:myDate[severity=(ERROR 2),
> summary=(/WEB-INF/xhtml............file.xhtml @507,51 value="#{bean.myDate}": Can't
> set property 'myDate' on class 'bean'
> to value '5/11/10 3:00 AM'.),
> detail=(/WEB-INF/xhtml........file.xhtml
> @507,51 value="#{bean.myDate}": Can't
> set property 'myDate' on class
> '...bean...' to value '5/11/10 3:00
> AM'.)]

2. Custom one: `<f:converter converterId="c2d"/>`

- getAsObject - returns the `java.util.Calendar` object out of the submitted `String`.
- getAsString - receives an `Object`, and returns the `String` formatted.

NOTE: this method was hacked so instead of expecting `java.util.Calendar`, to be complementary with `getAsObject` method. Instead, the hacked method `getAsString`, expects an `java.util.Date`, provided as parameter (by `ice:selectInputDate`) and returns the `String` formatted.

But still an error message occurs:

> [5/3/10 12:55:34:299 EEST] 0000001f
> D2DFaceletVie E
> com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler
> renderResponse Problem in
> renderResponse:
> java.util.GregorianCalendar
> incompatible with java.util.Date
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.GregorianCalendar
> incompatible with java.util.Date
> at com.icesoft.faces.component.selectinputdate.SelectInputDate.getTextToRender(SelectInputDate.java:252)

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the `Calendar` property with another getter/setter returning/taking a `Date`.

```
private Calendar calendar;

public Date getCalendarDate() {
    return (calendar != null) ? calendar.getTime() : null;
}

public void setCalendarDate(Date date) {
    if (calendar == null) {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear(); // Avoid timezone issues.
    }
    calendar.setTime(date);
}
```

A [JSF converter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) isn't going to work because this only does `Object`<-->`String` conversions, while we need a `Object`<-->`Date` conversion here. I don't do IceFaces, but there might be the chance that the particular component accepts a date string in a *certain* format pattern as well.  You would need to find that out and then write the covnerter accordingly to convert `Calendar`<-->`String` according this string format pattern. The [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is helpful in this.

Comment: Your code can lead to `NullPointerException`. The `public final void setTime(Date date)` method of the `Calendar` class of the Java framework does not check for null parameters and does this : `setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());` (checked in Java 1.8). Before calling `setTime`, you should check for null `date` param and reset `calendar` member.

Answer (score 3):

Either do as BalusC suggests, or simply set `value="#{yourBean.yourCalendar.time}`.