# How to bind a Date with calendar control in primefaces using binding attribute?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I want to bind a date with a calendar control after a specific value is selected from an autocomplete. But the following exception occurs :
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIComponent

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.schoolName}" completeMethod="#{rechargeCustomerBean.completeSchool}" required="true" />

<p:calendar mode="popup"
        navigator="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" effect="fadeIn"
        showButtonPanel="true"
        binding="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.expiryDate}" />
```

Comment: binding attribute should be given an el expression that maps to a server side UIComponent instance in a backing bean. You specified a Date type object. It should be object of type Calendar. From this object you need to get the date in the bean

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to bind?

Use the `value` attribute instead.

Also, add `<p:ajax` to your `calendar` to update the calendar and you are ready to go.
like this

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.schoolName}" completeMethod="#{rechargeCustomerBean.completeSchool}" required="true">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="idOfCalendar" /> 
</p:autoComplete>
```

Change

```
binding="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.expiryDate}"
```

into

```
value="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.expiryDate}"
```

so it will look like this

```
<p:calendar value="#{rechargeCustomerBean.school.expiryDate}" id="idOfCalendar"..... />
```

Answer (score 0):

use of `binding` attribute in `<p:calender>` might cause the problem...try chaging it with `value=#{...}`

also make sure your bean's "expiryDate" is of type Util.Date

hope this could resolve your problem..for detailed explanation [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766287/how-to-map-icefaces-iceselectinputdate-component-on-a-java-util-calendar-fiel)